# How to theme Angular Material to be more compact

Tags: angular, angular-material

I'm using Angular Material 7, and find the gutter spacing of the mat-form-field et. al. to be too large. On the desktop, the information density is very low.
I'd like to adjust this using theming, but Google only leads me to tutorials describing how to change colors. Does anyone have advice on how to make the spacing more compact without debugging dozens of Material css directives?

Comment: There is a GitHub thread in the project about that: https://github.com/angular/material2/issues/4597

This concept is now supported by the specification, but the Angular Material team has no ETA on that. The correct answer will be a hack at this moment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Material design has different density levels, Angular team finally implemented this and it is now an experimental feature in [Angular 10 release](https://github.com/angular/components/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md#1000-ice-dice-2020-06-24).

Answer (score 1):

You can set up density level at your theme definition like this:

```
$app-light-theme: mat-light-theme((
  color: (
    primary: $mat-primary-palette,
    accent: $mat-accent-palette
  ),
  density: -3
));
```

See: https://material.angular.io/guide/theming-your-components#3-include-the-theme-mixin-in-your-application

Comment: this does not work ? why?

Comment: I think this hasn't still been fully deployed, the old issue has been opened for almost 5 years now
https://github.com/angular/components/issues/4597

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to use css for your grid gutter size, you can use angular material with flex-layout and easily set your gutter size using fxLayoutGap="16px or 20px".
Here is the link [fxLayoutGap API](https://github.com/angular/flex-layout/wiki/fxLayoutGap-API).